# How to run a service in init (Android 8.1)

Tags: android, service, init, selinux, android-8.1-oreo

I want to run the service through Init. (Android 8.1, sepolicy=permissive)

The service executes the script file, and the script file is as follows.

```
tcc898x:/ # cat /system/bin/tcc_dxb_service
#!/system/bin/sh
echo ----------------
echo RICHGOLD.
echo ----------------
```

Service execution in init proceeds as follows.

```
tcc898x:/ # cat init.tcc898x.rc
(...)
on boot
    (...)
    start tcc_dxb_service
(...)
service tcc_dxb_service /system/bin/tcc_dxb_service
    class main
    user root
    u:object_r:tcc_dxb_service_exec:s0
```

And to add domain, sepolicy file is added as below.

```
# cat (Android 8.1 SDK)/device/(vendor)/(product)/sepolicy/tcc_dxb_service.te
type tcc_dxb_service, domain;
type tcc_dxb_service_exec, exec_type, system_file_type, file_type;
init_daemon_domain(tcc_dxb_service)
```

When the tcc_dxb_service service is executed, the following output is displayed.

```
tcc898x:/ # start tcc_dxb_service
init: could not get context while starting 'tcc_dxb_service'
```

**Please tell me how to register the domain in Sepolicy to run the service.**

Thanks.

Comment: https://blog.csdn.net/aa642531/article/details/83688365

Answer (score 2):

You have to

- prepend `seclabel` to the seclabel of your service definition,
- change `object_r` to `r`, and
- use the `tcc_dxb_service` type instead of `tcc_dxb_service_exec`.

```
service tcc_dxb_service /system/bin/tcc_dxb_service
    class main
    user root
    seclabel u:r:tcc_dxb_service:s0
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks your answer.

I referenced the [Android reference site](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/device-policy#label_new_services_and_address_denials) to add services to the project under development.

1. Added a service, 
   (init.{device}.rc)

```
service foo /system/bin/foo
    class core
```

2. Added label.
   ((android SDK)/device/(vendor)/(device)/sepolicy/file_contexts)

```
/system/bin/foo u:object_r:foo_exec:s0
```

3. Create a new domain.
   ((android SDK)/device/(vendor)/(device)/sepolicy/foo.te)

```
# foo sercie
# Integrated foo process
type foo, domain;
type foo_exec, exec,type, file_type;

# started by init
init_daemon_domain(foo)
```

(/system/bin/foo)

```
echo "-----"
echo "RICHGOLD"
echo "-----"
```

I set it like this. 
When building, the following error occurs.

```
FAILED: out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy 
/bin/bash -c "(out/host/linux-x86/bin/secilc -M true -G -c 30 out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/plat_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/plat_sepolicy.cil out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/27.0.cil_intermediates/27.0.cil out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/nonplat_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/nonplat_sepolicy.cil -o out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy.tmp -f /dev/null ) && (out/host/linux-x86/bin/sepolicy-analyze out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy.tmp permissive > out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy.permissivedomains ) && (if [ \"eng\" = \"user\" -a -s out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy.permissivedomains ]; then         echo \"==========\" 1>&2;       echo \"ERROR: permissive domains not allowed in user builds\" 1>&2;         echo \"List of invalid domains:\" 1>&2;         cat out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy.permissivedomains 1>&2;      exit 1;         fi ) && (mv out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy.tmp out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/sepolicy_intermediates/sepolicy )"
neverallow check failed at out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/nonplat_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/nonplat_sepolicy.cil:2715
  (neverallow base_typeattr_56_27_0 base_typeattr_57_27_0 (file (execute execute_no_trans entrypoint)))
    <root>
    allow at out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/nonplat_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/nonplat_sepolicy.cil:6207
      (allow foo foo_exec (file (read getattr map execute entrypoint open)))

neverallow check failed at out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/plat_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/plat_sepolicy.cil:4641 from system/sepolicy/public/domain.te:668
  (neverallow base_typeattr_56 base_typeattr_57 (file (execute execute_no_trans entrypoint)))
    <root>
    allow at out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/nonplat_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/nonplat_sepolicy.cil:6207
      (allow foo foo_exec (file (read getattr map execute entrypoint open)))

Failed to generate binary
Failed to build policydb
[  2% 110/5135] build out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/precompiled_sepolicy_intermediates/precompiled_sepolicy
FAILED: out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/precompiled_sepolicy_intermediates/precompiled_sepolicy 
/bin/bash -c "out/host/linux-x86/bin/secilc -M true -G -c 30        out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/plat_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/plat_sepolicy.cil out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/27.0.cil_intermediates/27.0.cil out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/nonplat_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/nonplat_sepolicy.cil -o out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/precompiled_sepolicy_intermediates/precompiled_sepolicy -f /dev/null"
neverallow check failed at out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/nonplat_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/nonplat_sepolicy.cil:2715
  (neverallow base_typeattr_56_27_0 base_typeattr_57_27_0 (file (execute execute_no_trans entrypoint)))
    <root>
    allow at out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/nonplat_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/nonplat_sepolicy.cil:6207
      (allow foo foo_exec (file (read getattr map execute entrypoint open)))

neverallow check failed at out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/plat_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/plat_sepolicy.cil:4641 from system/sepolicy/public/domain.te:668
  (neverallow base_typeattr_56 base_typeattr_57 (file (execute execute_no_trans entrypoint)))
    <root>
    allow at out/target/product/tcc898x/obj/ETC/nonplat_sepolicy.cil_intermediates/nonplat_sepolicy.cil:6207
      (allow foo foo_exec (file (read getattr map execute entrypoint open)))

Failed to generate binary
Failed to build policydb
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
17:24:01 ninja failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (43 seconds) ####
```

If init_daemon_domain (foo) is removed when a domain is created, 
((android SDK)/device/(vendor)/(device)/sepolicy/foo.te)

```
# foo sercie
# Integrated foo process
type foo, domain;
type foo_exec, exec,type, file_type;

# started by init
# init_daemon_domain(foo)
```

the log below is displayed after a normal build. 
When the service is executed,

```
# start foo
init: service foo does not have a SELinux domain defined
```

How do I add a domain?
Please give me tips on neverallow.

Thanks.

Comment: try this foo.te


type foo, domain;

type foo_exec, exec_type,  file_type;   ( in your original message, you had a type here exec,type insted of exec_type ) ) 

file_contexts


/system/bin/foo u:object_r:foo_exec:s0